# Capped / Constrained Weights

Tags: python, pandas, weighted

I have a dataframe of weights, in which I want to constrain the maximum weight for any one element to 30%. However in doing this, the sum of the weights becomes less than 1, so the weights of all other elements should be uniformly increased, and then repetitively capped at 30% until the sum of all weights is 1.

For example:

[image]

If my data is in a pandas data frame, how can I do this efficiently?
Note: in reality I have like 20 elements which I want to cap at 10%... so there is much more processing involved. I also intent to run this step 1000s of times.

Answer (score 1):

@jpp

The following is a rough approach, modified from your answer to iteratively solveand re-cap.  It doenst produce a perfect answer though... and having a while loop makes it inefficient.  Any ideas how this could be improved?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
cap = 0.1
df = pd.DataFrame({'Elements': list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'),
               'Values': [17,11,7,5,4,4,3,2,1.5,1,1,1,0.8,0.6,0.5]})
df['Uncon'] = df['Values']/df['Values'].sum()
df['Con'] = np.minimum(cap, df['Uncon'])

while df['Con'].sum() < 1 or len(df['Con'][df['Con']>cap]) >=1:
    df['Con'] = np.minimum(cap, df['Con'])
    nonmax = df['Con'].ne(cap)

    adj = (1 - df['Con'].sum()) * df['Con'].loc[nonmax] / 
    df['Uncon'].loc[nonmax].sum()

    df['Con'] = df['Con'].mask(nonmax, df['Con'] + adj)
    print(df)
    print(df['Con'].sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one vectorised solution. The idea is to calculate an adjustment and distribute it proportionately among the non-capped values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Elements': list('ABCDE'),
                   'Uncon': [0.53, 0.34, 0.06, 0.03, 0.03]})

df['Con'] = np.minimum(0.30, df['Uncon'])
nonmax = df['Con'].ne(0.30)

adj = (1 - df['Con'].sum()) * df['Uncon'].loc[nonmax] / df['Uncon'].loc[nonmax].sum()

df['Con'] = df['Con'].mask(nonmax, df['Uncon'] + adj)

print(df)

  Elements  Uncon  Con
0        A   0.53  0.3
1        B   0.34  0.3
2        C   0.06  0.2
3        D   0.03  0.1
4        E   0.03  0.1
```

Comment: thank you jpp, however this was a simple example, what about when the adjusted values breach the constraint? We need to iteratively re-solve the weights until they all sum to 1 and no individual value is > 0.3.  if there are many weights and the constraint is lower, often each iteration the lower weights will breach the cap. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: @cwse, Sorry, I don't understand the problem. The above answers your *original* question as stated, right? If you have another, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a more appropriate example.

Comment: jpp, please see my draft answer ^